# Why My Navbar is still horizontally scrolling ( Bootstrap)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive website , this is the URL http://waverin.com . I am able to make it responsive and navbar is almost working. Only issue is on a mobile device it provides a a little scrollbar making it not look so elegant.
[image: Scroll Allowed]

Comment: It would be great if any one could help me fixing this.

Comment: It would be great if you could supply with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the negative right margin here:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
         margin-right: -20px;
         margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Because the div is `position: static` at that width, the negative right margin causes that element to blow out by 20px, and thus you get the scroll.

Comment: I am basically a java developer .. I just wanted to know which tool helped you to analyze this issue. Firebug + experience or is it something other that I can also learn